# Issue with Google VR in Android

Tags: android, video, google-vr, 360-virtual-reality

I am facing this strange issue while working with the Google VR SDK while playing 360 videos.

I have implemented and run my application on my Samsung android phone and many other devices as well. It worked fine. Some devices run it using their sensors to view the 360 degree video and some uses finger swipes to move the video angle.

But today morning i tried to run the same Application on "Iball COBALT SOLUS 4G mobile". Having 5.1 Lollipop, with Accelerometer and Gyroscope sensor. As it does not have Compass/Magnetometer, it needs to be swiped manually with a finger to view 360 videos. But its not even working even after swiping it manually with my finger. Video is only visible with a fixed angle.

And I am able to swipe youtube 360 videos on the same device.Could not figure what might be the issue.

Comment: What precisely is your question in this issue? You have only stated a problem but not pointed out specifically which part needs solving.

Comment: @keithmaxx  - I am unable to to move the direction of 360 video using finger swipe,  as it is running on youtube application,  on the same phone.

Answer (score 0):

Interesting, it shouldn't be possible yet, based on [this post](https://support.google.com/cardboard/answer/6383058?p=vrview&rd=1). You can supposedly only do click and drag on a computer (browser), not Android.

Did you use specific settings to make swiping view rotation to work on particular phones?